# Changes in MS Access Form Not Automatically Updating Linked Tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am currently working on a Microsoft Access database where I have linked tables connected to a SQL Server backend. The setup involves a form in Access through which users make changes to the data. However, I've encountered an issue where changes made in the Access form only reflect the changes to the local tables of MS Access .But what I want is that it should also reflect changes to the linked tables of SQL server added through ODBC.

**Details**

- I have ensured that the form is bound to the correct table.
- The controls on the form are properly bound to corresponding fields.
- I am using VBA with the AfterUpdate event to trigger saving changes.
- Even after making changes and saving records through the form, the linked tables do not update unless I manually refresh them.

**Code Example**
Here is an example of the VBA code used in the `AfterUpdate` event:

```
Private Sub frmJobs_AfterUpdate()
    ' Save the current record
    DoCmd.DoMenuItem acFormBar, acRecordsMenu, acSaveRecord, , acMenuVer70

    ' Refresh the linked table
    CurrentDb.TableDefs("dbo_tblJobs").RefreshLink
End Sub
```

What could be causing this issue, and how can I ensure that changes made in the Access form are automatically reflected in the linked tables on SQL Server?

**Additional Details**

- MS Access version: 2013
- Linked table connection details: I used ODBC(x64 bit) to create connection between SQL Server and MS Access

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: With bound forms, you do not need *any* code to save the record to the underlying table.

Comment: What do you mean by *local tables of MS Access*? Actual local tables (non-linked)? Or the ODBC linked tables that show up under Tables in the navigation pane?

Comment: local tables means (non-linked)

Comment: @FizzaAkram Then you have to use `UPDATE` query after changes data.

Comment: Your form is bound to the local table, and that is WRONG.  Change the data source of the form to work on the linked table, and everything should work just fine, and you don't need any extra or special code here.

Answer (score 0):

Refresh the form:

```vb
Private Sub frmJobs_AfterUpdate()

    ' Save the current record.
    Me.Dirty = False

    ' Refresh the form. Should not be needed.
    Me.Refresh

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this but no result. It changes data in the local table but not in the linked table (of SQL Server).

Comment: Then you must use `Me.Requery`.

Comment: This suggests that your form is bound to the local table, and not the linked one. So, any and all updates to the form are going to the wrong table. This has ZERO to do with me.Refresh or anything else. Simple data entry shows that data going to the local table, and all the code, all the saving , and all the work here will NEVER work until the form is bound to the linked table and not the local table. it not the code that does not work, it is the fact of the form being bound to the wrong table....

Comment: Oh, I guess @AlbertD.Kallal nailed it.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Thank you. It worked for me. Really appreciate it.